# iOS Currency Format - remove the text before the symbol

Tags: ios, currency, nsnumberformatter

Is there a way to remove the text that comes before the currency symbol from a string output using NSNumberFormatter?

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.currencyCode = @"HKD";
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@1000]);

Output: HK$1,000.00
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to remove the HK before the $ without parsing the string and removing the text. Perhaps a property to set on NSNumberFormatter?

Comment: You don't want to remove `HK`. If you do, how will the user know what currency is being displayed? Someone if the USA will assume it us US dollars. Someone in Mexico will think it is Mexican pesos, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy I understand that but unfortunately this was what the boss has asked for :(

Comment: @rmaddy To be more clear, the user has the option to select which currency they would like to view. So essentially they will 'know' which currency they selected and thus will not need to see the text. Someone in USA will select US and someone in mexico may select mexico, in both cases they do not need to see US $ or MXD $ as they already know they are viewing currency in that particular country.

Comment: OK, then in those cases there is nothing to do. Some one with a locale of en_US will only see `$` and not `US$` (or `USD`). The issue only arises when the currency is formatted for an unrelated locale. You only get the extra letters when the currency formatter's locale doesn't match the currency code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid the extra characters is to set the formatter's local to match the chosen currency code. If you want to show `HKD` values as just `$` to a user not in Hong Kong, you need to also set the formatter's locale to a Hong Kong locale.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.currencyCode = @"HKD";
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh_HK"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@1000]);
```

This should show just `$1,000.00`.